# PHP Memory Limit not working

Tags: php, memory-management, apache2

> PHP Deprecated:  google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to
>   vendor/autoload.php in 2.0.0. This redirect will be removed in 2.1.
>   Please adjust your code to use the new location. in
>   /root/plus/plus/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php on line
>   19
>
> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /root/plus/plus/UploadAlbumPicasa.php on line 32
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 322957319 bytes) in
>   /root/plus/plus/UploadAlbumPicasa.php on line 80

I tried to increase the memory limit as can be seen in

**info.php**

```
memory_limit    1024M
```

But whenever I run the script, it tells me the message as shown above. The allowed memory exhausted error.

Any idea what is causing this issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: There is most likely a Memory Leak in your `UploadAlbumPicasa.php` file - can you show us the code?

Comment: Can you add the line where you are including autoload.php in your code, if you will go through my profile you can see, I have worked in this and may be my questions and answer can help you achieve this .

Comment: You are making changes in php.ini or using Ini_set in your code